# How can I implement a custom QueryStringConverter for RESTful WCF?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, extensibility

I've implemented a customized QueryStringConverter class and hooked it up using a customized WebHttpBehavior subclass. When I make a service call, it hits my breakpoint in the CanConvert override (and I return true for this parameter), but it never calls my ConvertStringToValue override, and ends up just passing null to the service call... why is ConvertStringToValue never called and how can I fix it?

Comment: UPDATE: This has been fixed in .Net 4.5

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
Microsoft were so sloppy with the implementation of this functionality that they merely newed up the standard QueryStringConverter instread of using the one configured in the configuration file.

There are no work arounds that actually work. The second one in the bug report doesn't actually work at all.

The short answer is that you cannot.
See the bug here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616486/bug-with-getquerystringconverter-not-being-called-by-webservicehost#tabs

It is still broken in framework 4.0.
My guess is that it's not important - so perhaps take the time to increase the counts on the bug.

Regards

Craig.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is quite old question. For any one who looking for some answer, you should be able to add the TypeConverter to your class which can convert type to and from string representation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.querystringconverter.aspx

> Types that have a TypeConverterAttribute that can convert the type to
>   and from a string representation.

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like this:

In contract file

```
    [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/TabelasAuxiliares?requestex={requestex}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        CadastrodeEscolasResponse TabelasAuxiliares(string requestex);
```

In the Service file

```
public CadastrodeEscolasResponse TabelasAuxiliares(string requestex)
        {

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CadastrodeEscolasRequest));
            StringReader rdr = new StringReader(requestex);
            CadastrodeEscolasRequest request = (CadastrodeEscolasRequest)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
}
```

Conslusion:
Call the service by sending Xml format data to a string parameter. Then convert the xml to the required class object. This way you can avoid creating QueryStringConvertor which is quite cumbersome. Hope this will help! This help is for all and not just for this post.