# passing objects in WCF service

Tags: wcf, rest

I am new WCF and resful service. I am learning how to pass objects in WCF service.

I have paste code and web.config file. I dont know why i am seeing this error.

Please help..

```
Operation 'saveDataGet' in contract 'IRestServiceImpl' has a query variable named   '  param1' of type 'GainSoft.TaskManager.Service.InputData', but type 'GainSoft.TaskManager.Service.InputData' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.  Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it  

originated in the code. 


Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation 'saveDataGet' in 
contract 'IRestServiceImpl' has a query variable named 'param1' of type 
'GainSoft.TaskManager.Service.InputData', but type 
'GainSoft.TaskManager.Service.InputData' is not convertible by    
 'QueryStringConverter'.  Variables for UriTemplate query values must have types that
 can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'.

public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public string saveDataGet(InputData param1)
    {
        return "Via GET: " + param1.FirstName + " " + param1.LastName;
    }
    public string saveDataPost(InputData param1)
    {
        return "Via POST: " + param1.FirstName + " " + param1.LastName;
    }



    public class MyQueryStringConverter : QueryStringConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
        {
            return (type == typeof(InputData)) || base.CanConvert(type);
        }
        public override object ConvertStringToValue(string parameter, Type parameterType)
        {
            if (parameterType == typeof(InputData))
            {
                string[] parts = parameter.Split(',');
                return new InputData { FirstName = parts[0], LastName = parts[1] };
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ConvertStringToValue(parameter, parameterType);
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
    {
        protected override QueryStringConverter GetQueryStringConverter(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            return new MyQueryStringConverter();
        }
    }

public interface IRestServiceImpl
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/InsertData?param1={param1}")]

    string saveDataGet(InputData param1);

   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/InsertData")]
   string saveDataPost(InputData param1);
 }
```

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour" >
      <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyWebHttpBehavior">
      <webHttp/>

    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738201/how-can-i-implement-a-custom-querystringconverter-for-restful-wcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot pass any complex data types as query parameter. use another verb such as POST or PUT depending on your requirements. you could also serialize InputData to json string or smth. and pass it this way.

Comment: Can show that from code example , link to blog or post will also be helpful.

Comment: sure, here you go, hope this helps

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709781/wcf-rest-parameters-involving-complex-types)

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like this:

In contract file

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/TabelasAuxiliares?requestex={requestex}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    CadastrodeEscolasResponse TabelasAuxiliares(string requestex);
```

In the Service file

```
public CadastrodeEscolasResponse TabelasAuxiliares(string requestex) {

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CadastrodeEscolasRequest));
    StringReader rdr = new StringReader(requestex);
    CadastrodeEscolasRequest request = (CadastrodeEscolasRequest)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
}
```

Conclusion: Call the service by sending XML format data to a string parameter. Then convert the XML to the required class object. This way you can avoid creating QueryStringConvertor which is quite cumbersome. Hope this will help! This help is for all and not just for this post.